# Preferred way to cross join a table with (0,1)^T?

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-join

I have a table T1, and I want to get a new table with twice the rows: An extra column which gets 0 (for one copy of T1) and 1 (for a second copy of T1).

In other words, I want to cross-join T1 with a constant table with one Boolean column and all possible values.

What's the best/most efficient/more appropriate way to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this with a cross join, you can do this:

```
select t.*, const.which
from t cross join
     (select 0 as which union all select 1 as which) const
```

This is definitely more efficient than UNION.  Whether it is more efficient than UNION ALL depends on the database engine.

If "t" is a subquery, then this is likely to be more efficient, since there is no chance that the subquery gets evaluated more than once.

Comment: [In MySQL `cross join` = `inner join` so probably need to use the comma syntax.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . You are correct that cross join = inner join.  However, the interpration wrong.  You can actually replace "cross join" in the above query with "inner join" and it works without the on clause.  If you carefully parse the documentation for mysql joins (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), you'll see that the "on" clause is optional.

Comment: Just spotted that as well. The MySQL behaviour isn't quite as bizarre as I thought.

Answer (score 2):

You mean a union?

```
select 0 as newfield, * from yourtable
union all
select 1, * from yourtable
```

Comment: Is the `as newfield` for the `1` implicit? And should you include it anyways?

Comment: A union takes the field names from the first select. It makes no difference.

Comment: This is a good answer.  However, it is better to use UNION ALL, so there is no wasted effort to try to remove duplicates.